# Echo if value is set and hide if value is empty

Tags: php

```
<?php
  if  (isset($firstname)) {
      echo ' is my first name';
  }
  else {
      echo ''; 
  }
  ?>
  if  (isset($secondname)) {
      echo ' is my second name';
  }
  else {
      echo ''; 
  }?>
```

I have HTML form with two fields (first name, second name), so if user fill first name with some value, it will be displayed like this:

***myname - is my first name***

And if he fill both, he will get

***myname - is my first name
mysecond - is my second name***

and if he don't input anything, both (first and second) will be hidden.

Problem is, when I input only one field via form, both fields get visible (one filled and one empty).

How to hide if one of them don't have value?

Comment: why do you have `?>` between your if statements?

Comment: ...yeah that's what I'd like to know as well, and what the rest of their code looks like, if coming from a form etc.

Comment: i make it in two <?php  ?> because this code is between HTML and FIRST and SECOND name fields have html code in a middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
$firstname = 'ravi';
if  (!empty($firstname)) {
      echo ' is my first name';
  }
  else {
      echo ''; 
  }

  $secondname = '';
  if  (!empty($secondname)) {
      echo ' is my second name';
  }
  else {
      echo ''; 
  }
```

Comment: Ravi, what is the difference between "isset" and "!empty" in this situation?

Comment: @Serbon In `php` `isset()` is function when ever  a form button is clicked the variable the input fields in the form can be fetch through `isset()`  function and their are other ways in php . go to this link and learn more [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if  (isset($firstname) && !empty($firstname)) {
      echo $firstname.' is my first name';
  }


  if  (isset($secondname) && !empty($secondname)) {
      echo $secondname.' is my second name';
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: `isset && !empty` is redundant. `!empty` implies `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

`isset` is your issue. The value is *set*, it just happens to be empty.

You might want to use `!empty` instead of `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a '?>' in the middle of your code. That might need to remove that.

Second, do you mean you need to set two variables then only you can get the echo ?
If you mean that then you can try this

```
<?php
if  ($firstname!= '' && $secondname != '') {
  echo $firstname.' is my first name '.$secondname.' is my second name' ;
}
else {
    echo ''; 
}
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$firstname        = 'Michael';
$firstname_suffix = 'is my first name';
$lastname         = 'Roth';
$lastname_suffix  = 'is my second name';
$myname           = '';

$myname .= !empty($firstname) ? $firstname . ' ' . $firstname_suffix : '';
$spc     = !empty($firstname) ? ', ' : '';
$myname .= !empty($lastname) ? $spc . $lastname . ' ' . $lastname_suffix : '';
$myname .= !empty($myname) ? '.' : '';

echo $myname;
?>
```

if the first name is set:

*Michael is my first name.*

if the first and second name is set:

*Michael is my first name, Roth is my second name.*

if only the second name is set:

*Roth is my second name.*

Answer (score -1):

So as i understood your question. you want to `echo` names when user fill firstname and secondname and with different conditions than.

Here is the code which matchs all yours conditions

```
 <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" >
            <p>Enter First name</p>

            <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <br>

            <p>Enter Second name</p>

            <input type="text" name="secondname">
            <br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit">
            <br>
        </form>

        <?php

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                $secondname = $_POST['secondname'];

                //NOW IF USER HAS FILL ALL INPUT FIELDS
                if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($secondname)){
                    echo "".$firstname."- is my first name ".$secondname." - is my second name";
                }
                //NOW IF BOTH FIELDS ARE EMPTY
                else if(empty($firstname) && empty($secondname)){
                    //DISPLAY NOTHING               
                }
                //NOW IF FIRST NAME IS FILLED AND SECONDNAME EMPTY
                else if(!empty($firstname) && empty($secondname)){
                    echo "".$firstname."- is my first name";
                }
                //NOW IF FIRST NAME IS EMPTY AND SECONDNAME FILLED
                else if(empty($firstname) && !empty($secondname)){
                    echo "".$secondname."- is my Second name";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

## IF ANY OF YOUR QUESTIONS TO BE ANSWERED THAN FREELY COMMENT